# WhenEvent&NDSolve: How to detect saddle point?

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I'm considering a simple ode. With the help of `WhenEvent` and `Discrete Variable` it  is possible to detect the sign  of the solution `x'[t]` and switch the ode accordingly(avoiding `Sign-function`).

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == 1 - x[t] - .05 sgn[t] (1 + x[t]) ,
x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1, sgn[0] == 1 ,WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0  , sgn[t] -> -sgn[t] ]}, {x, sgn}, {t, 0, 25}, DiscreteVariables -> {sgn[t] }] 

Plot[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t]}, {t, 0, 25}]
```

[image]

The sign-changes of `x'[t]`are detected very well until `t~=21`. Here the solution shows a saddle point.

My question: How to define two WhenEvents, which distinguish extrema(x'[t]==,x''[t]!=0)  and saddle points(x'[t]==,x''[t]==0)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't tell if the result is the expected one, but what about `WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0 && x''[t] == 0, sgn[t] -> -sgn[t]]`?

Comment: Consider `Plot[x''[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 25}]` and the discrete change of sign in `x''[t]` (i.e. such that `x''[t] != 0`) that occurs around `t~=21`.  It does not quite meet your definition of saddle.

Comment: @ C.E. Thanks, I tried the proposed Event, but NDSolve doesn't find a solution (MMA v 11.0.1)

Comment: @ Michael E2 Thanks, so it is perhaps an inflection point ! I tried an additional event `WhenEvent[x''[t] == 0  && x'[t] == 0  , sgn[t] -> sgn[t] ]` without success.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I guess I was wondering if the discontinuous change of sign of `x''[t]` disqualified it as a saddle or not.  I was guessing that you would include it, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit tricky: First, in `WhenEvent[]`, only the "state" variables are substituted. This means you can't use the highest order derivative (maybe WRI should rethink that).  One trick is to differentiate the ODE to raise the order, but that doesn't work here because the ODE is discontinuous.  I resorted to using the "right-hand side" of the ode as a substitute for `x''[t]`.  Second, getting the change of sign in `x''[t]` is tricky because it is discontinuous at the event `x'[t] == 0`.  However, you can examine `x''[t]` on both sides of the event with `rhs[x[t], ±sgn[t]]`.  From these two values, you can deduce whether the second derivative changes sign or not.

```
vars = {x, sgn, extrema, saddle};
rhs[x_, s_] := 1 - x - .05 s (1 + x);
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] == rhs[x[t], sgn[t]],
    x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1,
    sgn[0] == 1, extrema[0] == 0, saddle[0] == 0,
    WhenEvent[
     x'[t] == 0 && rhs[x[t], sgn[t]] rhs[x[t], -sgn[t]] > 0,
     {extrema[t] -> 1 + extrema[t], sgn[t] -> -sgn[t]}],
    WhenEvent[
     x'[t] == 0 && rhs[x[t], sgn[t]] rhs[x[t], -sgn[t]] <= 0,
     {saddle[t] -> 1 + saddle[t], sgn[t] -> -sgn[t]}]},
   vars, {t, 0, 25}, DiscreteVariables -> Rest@vars];

Plot[Through[vars[t]] /. First@sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 25}, 
 PlotLegends -> vars]
```

[image]

Comment: @ MichaelE2 Thank you for your answer, I have to analyse in detail! The saddle is well detected but  `sgn` shouldn't change!. I changed the saddle -event to `s[t]-> s[t]` but doesn't work .

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The saddle event presumes that `sgn[t]` changes sign.  If you do not change its sign, then `x''[t]` will not change sign and there will be an extremum, not a saddle.  I'm not sure why you want `sgn[t]` not to change at a potential saddle, but if it's to prevent saddles in the solution, then it seems to me it's working (except my variables `extrema` and `saddle` no longer count extremas and saddles, which seems unimportant and/or fixable).

Comment: @  Michael E2  : `sgn[t]~Sign[x'[t]]` is what I'm looking for. I agree that x''[t] must change sign in the saddle point. In the plot of your answer I see a positive slope of the blue curve  near the saddle.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann OK, I'll try to think about `sgn[t]~Sign[x'[t]]` -- discontinuities can be tricky.  I don't think in every case there is a solution to an ODE with discontinuous coefficients.  Plot `x'[t]` over a small range including the saddle: it decreases to zero (approximately) and then increases immediately with an angle like absolute value.  A discrete plot should show a line segment with a positive slope, since an instantaneously zero slope is impossible to draw via line segments (which is what `Plot[]` does).

Answer (score 3):

Here are some thoughts building on @MichaelE2's answer.

I'm visually oriented, so I converted your system into two first-order ODEs (with `v[t]==x'[t]`) to look at this in the phase-plane.

```
sol = NDSolve[{
  v'[t] == 1 - x[t] - 0.05 sgn[t] (1 + x[t]),
  x'[t] == v[t],
  x[0] == 0, v[0] == 1, sgn[0] == 1, 
  WhenEvent[v[t] == 0, sgn[t] -> -sgn[t]]},
  {x, v, sgn}, {t, 0, 25}, DiscreteVariables -> {sgn[t]}][[1]];
```

First make sure nothing changed:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], sgn[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 25}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we can plot the `x[t]` vs `v[t]=x'[t]` phase plane.  The tricky part is there are two sets of streams depending on `sgn[t]`.  I made the `sgn[t]==1` streams blue and the `sgn[t]==-1` ones gray.

```
{xmin, xmax} = {-0.2, 2.4}; {vmin, vmax} = {-1.2, 1.4};
sp1 = StreamPlot[{v, 1 - x - 0.05 (1 + x)},
  {x, xmin, xmax}, {v, vmin, vmax},
  StreamStyle -> Lighter[Blue, 0.5], PlotRangePadding -> 0];
sp2 = StreamPlot[{v, 1 - x + 0.05 (1 + x)},
  {x, xmin, xmax}, {v, vmin, vmax}, StreamStyle -> Gray];
Show[sp1, sp2, Graphics[Line[{{xmin, 0}, {xmax, 0}}]], FrameLabel -> {"x", "v=x'"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Well, that's an eye-full, but look along the `v==0` line and notice that the blue and gray arrows agree in direction on the outside but in the middle they are pointed at each other.

Now plot the numerical solution and color-code it based on `sgn[t]`:

```
pp = ParametricPlot[{x[t], v[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 25}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, If[(sgn[t] /. sol) > 0, Blue, Black]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick];
Show[sp1, sp2, pp, Graphics[Line[{{xmin, 0}, {xmax, 0}}]], FrameLabel -> {"x", "v=x'"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Zooming in on the interesting part:

```
{xmin, xmax} = {0.75, 1.2}; {vmin, vmax} = {-0.2, 0.2};
...
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So I'd say that `NDSolve` is doing exactly what you asked: switch `sgn[t]` when `x'[t]==0` and then carry on.

If you want one equation for `v'[t]` when `Sign[v[t]]>0` and the other when `Sign[v[t]]<0`, why not just use `Sign`?

```
sol = NDSolve[{
     v'[t] == 1 - x[t] - .05 Sign[v[t]] (1 + x[t]),
     x'[t] == v[t],
     x[0] == 0, v[0] == 1}, {x, v}, {t, 0, 25}][[1]];

Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 25}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here the solution gets trapped once it hits the region where the streams point at each other.  We can find that region by solving where each vector field changes directions:

```
Solve[1 - x - 0.05 (1 + x) == 0, x]
Solve[1 - x + 0.05 (1 + x) == 0, x]
(* {{x -> 0.904762}} {{x -> 1.10526}} *)
```

Putting it together:

```
{xmin, xmax} = {0.7, 1.2}; {vmin, vmax} = {-0.2, 0.2};
Show[
  StreamPlot[{v, 1 - x - Sign[v] 0.05 (1 + x)},
  {x, xmin, xmax}, {v, vmin, vmax},
  StreamStyle -> Gray, StreamPoints -> Fine],
  ParametricPlot[{x[t], v[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 25}, PlotStyle -> Red],
  Graphics[{Blue, Opacity[0.2], Rectangle[{xmin, 0}, {xmax, vmax}]}],
  Graphics[{Black, Thick, Line[{{0.904762, 0}, {1.10526, 0}}]}],
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "x'=v"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {vmin, vmax}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful comprehensive answer. With my attempt I tried to verify the solution of NDSolve of the ode with `Sign` (expecting a asymptotic solution `x[t]==1`). I need some time to elaborate your answer...

Comment: No prob. I think it could end up anywhere on that line segment from x=0.905 to 1.105.

Comment: That's the point where I'm struckling: If you  check the residuum of the solution you'll see a value near to zero for t<21, but for t>21 you see nonvanishing switching constant values. Does that mean the numerical solution doesn't approximate the ode for t>21???

Comment: Could you explain more about what you meant by the residuum of the solution?

Comment: If you substitude the numerical solution found by NDSolve into the ode you will get a time dependend expression . That's what I call residuum(sorry faulty translation...) and which is called residual! Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: No worries!  `Plot[Evaluate[x'[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 25}]` looks like I'd expect -- oscillating until it gets trapped around `t=21`, then flat.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: No I meant something like  `Plot[-v'[t] + 1 - x[t] - .05 Sign[v[t]] (1 + x[t])/.sol,{t,...}]`

Comment: I imagine NDSolve doesn’t like it when the right hand side is discontinuous like that, but the phase plane convinces me that this solution is basically correct.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I believe it's the same as the problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200664/4999).  I don't see how to use `sgn` to get around the issue with `Sign`.  (I personally am convinced that `Sign` is the right way to go, and the linked problem gives the correct solution.)

Comment: One more thought.  There's one other atypical thing about your system that results in the continuous range of equilibria (a degenerate result).  That's the fact that the x-isocline of v=0 perfectly overlaps the v-isocline given by that line segment.  That explains why the `Tanh` approximation in your previous question leads to a unique outcome -- it slightly bends the "v-isocline" to result in a unique equilibrium point.

Comment: @ Michael E2 Never ending story... I was looking for an analytic solution of the "Sign-ode" to verify `NDSolve solution`. That's why I formulated the "sgn-question".

Comment: @ ChrisK From the physical expectation the "Tanh version" gives more pausibel   results from the engineering point of view.

Comment: @Ulrich, if you put a space between the @ and the Michael, I don't get notified of your response. -- BTW, the use of `sgn` as a discrete variable is similar to how `NDSolve` implements `Sign` and other discontinuous functions.